# The memory corruption problem of C++ list

Tags: c++, list, qt, memory-corruption

I'm new to c++, and I need to use list container for my 3D marker-based watershed function. But I get strange bugs when I use list container. May I know what's wrong with my code?

Thank you so much!

I used a vector of list to save the wait-to-search pixel index.
I declare the variable in this way (`GVInt32` is `int32_t`):

```
vector<list<GVInt32>> toSearchList;
```

And I used these two kinds of operations of list:

1. Add a new wait-to-search index at the end of a list

```
toSearchList[cnt].push_back(newidx);
```

2. Remove a searched element at the middle of a list(`it` is `list<GVInt32>::iterator`):

```
it = toSearchList[cnt].erase(it);
```

But I get two kinds of errors:

1. `malloc(): memory corruption` when I do
   `toSearchList[cnt].push_back(newidx);`
2. I get not accessible elements in the end of the list when I inspect the variable in debugger:

```
[Not accessible elements][1]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/flJg3.png

The IDE is QT creator 4.15.2

The system is Ubuntu 18.04

**The full code**

watershed_wz.cpp:

```
#include "watershed_wz.h"

WaterShed_WZ::WaterShed_WZ()
{

}


array<GVInt32, 6> WaterShed_WZ::getNeighbor_WZ(const GVInt32 idx, const GVInt32 width, const GVInt32 height, const GVInt32 thick) {

    GVInt32 SLICE = width * height;
    GVInt32 z = idx / SLICE;
    GVInt32 y = (idx%SLICE) / width;
    GVInt32 x = idx % width;

    array<GVInt32, 6> nIndex;
    nIndex[0] = (x == 0) ? -1 : (idx - 1);
    nIndex[1] = ((x + 1) == width) ? -1 : (idx + 1);
    nIndex[2] = (y == 0) ? -1 : (idx - width);
    nIndex[3] = ((y + 1) == height) ? -1 : (idx + width);
    nIndex[4] = (z == 0) ? -1 : (idx - SLICE);
    nIndex[5] = ((z + 1) == thick) ? -1 : (idx + SLICE);

    return nIndex;
}



void WaterShed_WZ::Watershed3D_WZ(
    const Mat im,
    const GVInt32 width,
    const GVInt32 height,
    const GVInt32 thick,
    GVInt32* label,
    const vector<vector<GVInt32>> marker)
{
    //<Parameter>
    //<image>  the image for watershed
    //<width>  the width of the image
    //<height> the height of the image
    //<thick>  the thick of the image
    //<label>  the map to save result. need to allocate memory before use watershed
    //<marker> the marker's index

//    const GVByte* image=im.data;

    auto t0 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    QTextStream out(stdout);


//    const GVInt32 SZ_slice = width * height;
//    const GVInt32 SZ = SZ_slice * thick;
    const GVInt32 markerNum = marker.size();

    // create toSearchList. Saved pixel connected to labeled pixels and wait to search
    vector<list<GVInt32>> toSearchList;
    toSearchList.resize(markerNum);

    // set label to INIT (unsearched)
//    ::memset(label, -1, sizeof(GVInt32) * SZ);

    // initialize
    array<GVInt32, 6> nIdx;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < markerNum; i++)
    {
        for (GVInt32 idx : marker[i])
        {
            // initialize label (which can be considered as a map of pointer to labelBar)
            label[idx] = i + 1;
            nIdx = getNeighbor_WZ(idx, width, height, thick);
            for (GVInt32 newidx : nIdx)
            {
                if (newidx != -1)
                {
                    if (label[newidx] == -1) {

                        toSearchList[i].push_back(newidx);

                        label[newidx] = -2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //watershed
    GVByte h;
    GVInt32 idx;
    for (int h_cnt = 0; h_cnt < (1+(int)GV_BYTE_MAX); h_cnt++) // water height
    {
        h = (GVByte)h_cnt;
        for (GVInt32 cnt = 0; cnt < markerNum; cnt++) { // for each marker

            list<GVInt32>::iterator it = toSearchList[cnt].begin();
            while (!toSearchList[cnt].empty())
            {
                // for each pixel connected to the cnt-th labeled region

                idx = *it;
                // if this pixel is higher than water, ignore it
                if (im.at<unsigned char>(idx) > h)
                {
                    ++it;
                    if(it == toSearchList[cnt].end())
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                // this pixel is lower than water, assign it
                label[idx] = cnt + 1;
//                L.at<int>(idx)=cnt + 1;

                // add new neighbor
                nIdx = getNeighbor_WZ(idx, width, height, thick);
                for (GVInt32 newidx : nIdx)
                {
                    if (newidx != -1)
                    {
                        if (label[newidx]== -1) {
                            toSearchList[cnt].push_back(newidx);
                            label[newidx] = -2;
//                            L.at<int>(newidx)=-2;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // erase searched pixel
                it = toSearchList[cnt].erase(it);

                if(it == toSearchList[cnt].end())
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    auto t1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto dt = 1.e-9 * chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t1 - t0).count();
    out << "Watershed used " << dt << " seconds.\n\n" << Qt::endl;
}
```

watershed_wz.h:

```
#ifndef WATERSHED_WZ_H
#define WATERSHED_WZ_H

#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES

#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <list>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp> //basic building blocks of opencv
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp> // image io
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp> //image display
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTextStream>

#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

typedef unsigned char          GVByte;
typedef int32_t               GVInt32;
//typedef uint32_t               GVInt32U;

const GVByte              GV_BYTE_MAX = UCHAR_MAX;


class WaterShed_WZ
{
public:
    WaterShed_WZ();
    static array<GVInt32, 6> getNeighbor_WZ(const GVInt32 idx, const GVInt32 width, const GVInt32 height, const GVInt32 thick);
    static void Watershed3D_WZ(
            const Mat im,
            const GVInt32 width,
            const GVInt32 height,
            const GVInt32 thick,
            GVInt32* label,
            const vector<vector<GVInt32>> marker);
};

#endif // WATERSHED_WZ_H
```

Comment: Without looking at your code, the only problem I can see is that cnt might not be a valid index.

Comment: Compile it with `-g` and run it under `valgrind`. `valgrind` will tell you exactly what incorrect memory operations are happening, on which line and what the incorrectly accessed memory used to be (in case of a double-free, use-after-free or the like).

Answer (score 0):

try delete `[cnt]` index everywhere like this

```
toSearchList[cnt].end() --> toSearchList.end()
```

Comment: Hi Omer, Thank you for your suggestion. I'm using vector of list to save the to-search pixels. Do you mean that I actually can't use list as the element of vector?

Comment: I use vector of list because I have several markers, and each marker need to have its own to-search pixel list.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?